# IF/CASE Statement SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

I am unsure how to code this. Here are the scenarios I am needing in the IF statement. Should this be broken up into two different IF statements or could I possibly use CASE? I am new to programming so any help would be appreciated.

Scenerios:  IF selling_flag = 'N' and calculation_flag = 'Y' THEN return list_price. IF selling_flag = 'Y' and calculation_flag = 'Y' THEN return customer_price. IF calculation_flag = 'N' THEN return unit_selling

Currently I have:

```
IF selling_flag = 'N' AND calculation_flag = 'Y' THEN
  return list_price;
ELSE  
  return customer_price;      
END IF; 

IF calculation_flag = 'N' THEN
return selling_price;
END IF; 
END;
```

Thank you.

Comment: yes, this should be done as a case statement.  I'm not overly familiar with plsql, but you can't really return different values within an if/else statement in any sort of SQL, rather it's used for checking if the entire logic should branch off to some other set of logic.

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially do it this way [Case Statements PLSQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/case_statement.htm):

```
CASE 
    WHEN selling_flag = 'N' AND calculation_flag = 'Y' THEN list_price;
    WHEN selling_flag = 'Y' AND calculation_flag = 'Y' THEN customer_price;
    ELSE selling_price;
END CASE;
```

Where you have your two conditions and if neither are met it defaults to selling_price.

Comment: This would return the correct value in most syntax (mysql, postrgres, teradata, etc) but not sure about PLSQL specifically.

Comment: Ahh you're right.  I'm missing some semicolons and the closing is wrong.  I'll update it.

Answer (score 1):

If this is PL/SQL code, you would normally use `elsif`:

```
IF selling_flag = 'N' AND calculation_flag = 'Y' THEN
  return list_price;
ELSIF selling_flag = 'Y' AND calculation_flag = 'Y'
  return customer_price;      
ELSIF calculation_flag = 'N' THEN
  return selling_price;
END IF;
```

This might also be written as:

```
IF calculation_flag = 'Y' THEN
  IF selling_flag = 'N' THEN
    return list_price;
  ELSE 
    return customer_price;
  END IF;     
ELSE
  return selling_price;
END IF;
```